# javascript variable undefined or null

Tags: javascript

couldn't find a specfic answer elsewhere.  I'm totally new to JS and trying to pull a value out of a form and write it to the page.  The result when I try to write ProductName is undefined, and when I try to write ProductNameElement is null.  I'm sure it's to do with the form values being empty when the page loads but not sure after that...

```
<script>

    var ProductNameElement = document.getElementById("ProductName");
    var ProductName = ProductNameElement.value;

    function showname(){

    document.write(ProductName);

    }

</script>

<h2>Revenues</h2>

<div class="number">Product Name: <input type="text" id="ProductName" value=""></input></div>

<input type="button" value"showname" onclick="showname();"></input>
```

Comment: nope, it's that the HTML parser did not yet have a chance to know about the two elements by the time it got to your script, because your script is located and run *before* the definition of the tags it references. Better put that code as a function in the `onload` event handler of your page.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - you're right, misread the code - I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the first two lines of your script too early BEFORE the elements in your page have been parsed and placed into the DOM.  Because of that, the `ProductName` element doesn't exist yet when you're trying to find it with `document.getElementById("ProductName");`.

Place your script right before the `</body>` tag and then all your page elements will be available when you run your script.  Or, just put all your code in the `showname` function that isn't called until the click event.

```
function showname(){

    var ProductNameElement = document.getElementById("ProductName");
    var ProductName = ProductNameElement.value;

    document.write(ProductName);
}
```

And, as others have said, using `document.write()` after the documented has been loaded will cause the existing document to be cleared and a new empty document will be created.  This is pretty much never what you want.  If you're just doing this for debugging, use `console.log(ProductName)` and look at the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the element and the value inside the function, otherwise they aren't available, and the change of the value isn't caught

```
<script>
    function showname(){
        var ProductNameElement = document.getElementById("ProductName");
        var ProductName = ProductNameElement.value;

        document.write(ProductName);
    }
</script>

<h2>Revenues</h2>

<div class="number">
    Product Name: <input type="text" id="ProductName" value="" />
</div>

<input type="button" value"showname" onclick="showname();" />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wzzuhzwg/)

And inputs are self closing, and you should stop using `document.write`, it will overwrite the entire document and remove everything that is currently there !